# Angular2: One instance of module in multiple modules

Tags: angular, typescript, module, components

Let's make example for `ng2-translate`  plugin.

I have root `AppModule`, and children `TopPanelModule` and `PagesModule`.

---

I configure `ng2-translate` for `AppModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot({
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json'),
    deps: [Http]
  })],
  exports: []
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {    
  }
}
```

---

In `AppComponent` I set languages and basic configuration for `TranslateModule`.

```
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {
    translateService.addLangs(["en", "fr"]);
    translateService.setDefaultLang('fr');

    const browserLang = 'fr';
    translateService.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');    
  }
}
```

---

And then I'm trying to use `TranslateModule` in children modules components - `TopPanelComponent`, `PagesComponent`. It does'n work. Pipe not exists error, no translate etc..

---

For resolving this problem, I create a separate module `MyTranslateModule`, configure `TranslateModule` on it, and use this module in my `PagesModule` and `TopPanelModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot({
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json'),
    deps: [Http]
  })],
  exports: [TranslateModule]
})
export class MyTranslateModule {
  constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {
    translateService.addLangs(["en", "fr"]);
    translateService.setDefaultLang('fr');

    const browserLang = 'fr';
    translateService.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');

    console.log('AdminTrModule: calling');
  }
}
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MyTranslateModule]
})
export class PagesModule{

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [MyTranslateModule]
})
export class TopPanelModule{

}
```

---

**This is important part.** It works! But I think it creates a two instances of TranslateModule, so, when I change transalte langauge by calling in `TopComponent` `translateService.use('en')`, it change language in `TopPanelModule`, but not in `PagesModule`.

Comment: Are you using lazy loading?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, if i know right, angular2 use lazy loading by default.

Comment: No, lazy loading is used when you use `loadChildren` in routes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Yes, I'm using lazy loading

Comment: That's what causes multiple instance to be generated. By default all providers from all imported modules are registered in the applications root scope, but lazy loaded modules get their own root scope (which is a child scope of the application root scope). When a component or service from a lazy loaded module injects some service and the lazy loaded module has it register an instance from there is injected, only if the lazy loaded module doesn't have a provider DI checks with the application root scope. All non-lazy loaded modules that request the same dependency get one from the app root

Comment: Check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html. I never dived into that topic about how to ensure services of lazy loaded modules get registered at the application root scope but I guess it is possible. Also check the link at the bottom (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html)

Comment: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/209

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a forRoot function in module 'MyTranslateModule'

```
export class MyTranslateModule {

static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyTranslateModule ,
      providers: [TranslateService,TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS]
    };
  }

}
```

then import MyTranslateModule in appModule
as following

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [App],
  declarations: [
    App
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    MyTranslateModule.forRoot(),
    PagesModule,
    TopPanelModule
  ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency ]
})
```

in this case translate service will be created as singleton "one instance along the application"