# NgRx : store module creating several instances

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am encountering an issue with my code, using ngRx. Since the project is huge and it is more of a design question, I'm sorry I'm not providing a minimal and reproducting example.

I have a project with this structure :

```
AppModule
    PrimaryOutletModule
        SidenavComponent
        HeaderComponent

ExploitationComponentsModule [lazy loaded in AppRouting]
    MapComponent
    MaService

ServicesModule [imported in AppModule]
    HttpServicesModule
        ExploitationServicesModule
            ExploitationService
```

In this structure, I add this module to `AppModule` :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(exploitationReducers),
  ]
})
export class ExploitationStoreModule { }
```

Without any issue, all of my code works well. But when I add it to `PrimaryOutletModule`, `ExploitationComponentsModule`, and `ExploitationServicesModule`, and remove it from `AppModule` it stops working.

I want to remove it from the AppModule to avoid creating globally accessible stores (I want to give them meaningful scopes)

My first thought is to log the `select` and `dispatch` events, and when I do so, I see that events aren't caught. After adding this to the module :

```
constructor() { console.log('Store module instance created'); }
```

I see two instances. Following [this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243958/angular2-one-instance-of-module-in-multiple-modules), I realize that I have to use the `forRoot` method of the `StoreModule`.

But since my `ExploitationStoreModule` is already using it, I look for a solution and stumble upon [this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672816/can-lazy-loaded-modules-share-the-same-instance-of-a-service-provided-by-their-p), saying that lazy loaded modules are creating new instances of modules.

If I understood it correctly, I am using `forRoot` twice, resulting in two instances of my `ExploitationStoreModule`.

Since I want to give correct scopes to my modules and don't let them access stores they don't have business with (for instance, `ExploitationModule` should not have access to `SupervisionStore`), I would like to not be forced to import all of my Store modules into my `AppModule`.

That brings the question : **how should one declare stores in an application so that they aren't global and only provided in their respective modules ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `storeModule.forFeature` in the feature modules. 
But the state will become available to your whole application when the module is being loaded.

Some extra resources:

- [NgRx Docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#feature-module-state-composition)
- [Sharing data between modules is peanuts](https://blog.angularindepth.com/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts-3f40fcb38dd)
- [Store Setup](https://redux.js.org/faq/storesetup#store-setup-multiple-stores)

A store holds the whole state tree of your application, and the following the best practices you should only have one store (there are edge cases where performance might be an issue where you would need multiple stores, I linked to the redux docs which have a great explanation).

If you import your store into your component with eg `Store<FooState>`, typescript only knows about the `FooState` but in fact your store holds your whole application's state, eg also `BarState`.

But personally I don't need to access the store inside my components because I'm using selectors, which doesn't really need the store type. For example `this.store.select(selectEmployees)`.

Comment: So that means once the `Exploitation` module is loaded, if I add a `ExploitationStore` to my `SupervisionComponent`, it will have access to it ? Does that mean you can't scope a store to a single module (other than the app module) ? Anyway, +1 for the information

Comment: A store holds the whole state tree of your application, and the following the best practices you should only have one store (there are edge cases where performance might be an issue where you would need multiple stores, I linked to the redux docs which have a great explanation).

Comment: If you import your store into your component with eg `Store<FooState>`, typescript only knows about the `FooState` but in fact your store holds your whole application's state, eg also `BarState`.

Comment: But personally I don't need to access the store inside my components because I'm using selectors, which doesn't really need the store type. For example `this.store.select(selectEmployees)`

Comment: Okay, so best practice is a single store, not several ones ? And I understand that components only understand the `State` provided, but I would like to prevent devs from importing states that aren't related to the module they're in. Seems like it isn't possible, bummer ... Thank you for all that information though, very helpful !